# Secure connection between computer and phone

Tags: windows-7, iphone, webserver, sftp, ssh-tunnel

I have never done any form of hosting and wonder how I would go about creating a **secure** small server between my computer and phone? 
I don't want to access everything, just a portion of the PC data from the phone, within the same wifi range. Threat model is high.
*windows 7 - Iphone*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have listed some connection types in your tags, I'll explain those.

---

The webserver part is the easiest.

You simply need to run a webserver on the PC. There are many ways to do this depending on your skills and what you want to achieve/learn. My own favourite is using JavaScript and Node.JS but this may be rather complex for first time use. Node.JS allows you to very quickly run your own web service and has plenty of helper libraries such as the excellent Express library.

Alternatively, you might find it easier to grab something called WAMP. This gives you a full set of web services including Apache (the web server), PHP (which gives you a dynamic language for creating web applications) and MySQL (a database). There are various variations on that theme too, WAMP is probably the most popular. You can also run the native Internet Information Service (IIS) which is an optional Windows service you can turn on, this does the same as Apache. The benefit of WAMP is that it uses the same capabilities as cheap hosting web services so there are lots of tutorials and instructions.

You mention security so also worth mentioning that you need to set up Apache with SSL/TLS security - there are many tutorials on doing that.

---

Then you've mentioned SFTP and SSH. These are related and generally 1 tool will provide both services. On Windows you will need an application such as [FreeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/) or [WinSSHd](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) (free for personal use) to provide the SSH server part. This should also give you SFTP.

---

The last part of the puzzle is to use the right client apps on the iPhone. The web browser isn't an issue of course but SFTP and SSH is slightly more problematic. You need one or more apps for that. SFTP is the easiest as there are many apps that will transfer files over SFTP, Goodreader is my own preference. SSH is the hardest as this is rather more specialised but there are plenty of SSH clients listed in the app store. Most cost money though.

---

As you've said that the threat level is high, a couple of additional points.

For SFTP/SSH, make sure you have the security correctly configured. Also, use certificate based authentication with a very strong encryption level. Make sure any passcodes are also very strong.

On the web side, I would recommend doing your learning on WAMP first so that you understand all the components. But for really secure use, I would recommend ditching WAMP and going with Node.JS along with a strong TLS configuration. Node.JS also has a number of user management helper libraries that you might also find helpful.

One final point on the web side, you might want to investigate the use of SASL which authenticates the user connection to the server (SSL/TLS authenticates the server to the user).

An alternative secure setup is to create a VPN on the PC and connect to that from the iPhone. Then all traffic from the phone will be encrypted to the PC. This would let you restrict the web and other services to only being accessible on the PC itself & the VPN, the iPhone would essentially be directly connected to the PC.

Comment: I have PIA VPN on my phone and PC already, is there any way I could use that or do I need to disable that and configure my own VPN?

Comment: Late edit: PIA support says this is not possible.

Comment: Wrong kind of VPN anyway. That type is to hide your real location/identity on the Internet. You need something to create a private connection from your phone to your desktop.